# How do I insert columns in my SQL table, where column name is a variable?

Tags: python, sql

I want to insert columns into my SQL table. Column name is a variable (read from an array).

I'm getting this error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

```py
for i in range(0, 100):
    conn.cursor().execute("ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD (?) real", (arr[i]))
```

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around the column name.

Comment: I don't think you can use parameters with DDL statements (i.e. creating or altering tables).  You'll have to build the statement as a literal string, i.e. `"ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD " + arr[i] + " real"`.  Be sure `arr[i]` is validated, because unfortunately this method leaves you open to injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try executing with this instead?

```
 conn.cursor().execute(("ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD (columnName) real").format(columnName=arr[i]))
```